# Determining if day has passed PHP

Tags: php

trying to figure the following out :

I have a club that runs 3 days a week, Tuesday, Thursday and Saturday.

I want to print out the next club date from this week, so if Tuesday is the next meeting print out "Tuesday" or if today is Tuesday, print "Today", same for Thursday and Saturday.

I have the following code :

```
<?php
  $current = date('l', strtotime('now'));
  $tuesday = date('l', strtotime('tuesday this week'));
  $thursday = date('l', strtotime('thursday this week'));
  $saturday = date('l', strtotime('saturday this week'));

  if ($tuesday < $current) {
    echo "Tuesday in the future";
  } else if ($thursday < $current) {
    echo "Thursday in the future";
  } else if ($saturday < $current) {
    echo "Saturday in the future";
  }
 ?>
```

And this is where i fell short and couldn't figure it out....as it always just prints "Tuesday in the future".

Any help, suggestions or explanations would be grealy welcome!

Thanks
E

Comment: Have in mind that this method without specifying hour will return `Today` even if it is already 23:59 in a day of training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing string with `date('l')`. Change `date('l')` with `date('Ymd')`, or just leave `strtotime`, then you can compare numbers. You may need a "tuesday next week" if sunday.

```
<?php

$current = strtotime('now');
$tuesday = strtotime('tuesday this week');
$thursday = strtotime('thursday this week');
$saturday = strtotime('saturday this week');
$nextTuesday = strtotime('tuesday next week');

if ($tuesday > $current) {
    echo "Tuesday in the future";
} else if ($thursday > $current) {
    echo "Thursday in the future";
} else if ($saturday > $current) {
    echo "Saturday in the future";
} else if($nextTuesday > $current) {
    echo "Tuesday in the future";
}
```

Comment: strtotime alone will do the trick since it returns a unix timestamp

Comment: Good call @RisingSun

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help! Its really helped a lot! Although i do still have 1 problem, what if the day is today, how would i print "Today", for example, today is Thursday, but the output from the code is "Saturday", ideally id want it to be "Thursday" since our club night is tonight! :) TIA

Comment: You can check the date with available days of the week the the club is open, like `if (in_array(date('l'), ['Tuesday','Thursday','Saturday'])) { echo "Today!";}`

Comment: Thankyou!! Let me run a scenario, if tuesday has passed, how can i add a class to a div for example if != tuesday echo "d-none" that sort of thing...? Same for the other days! :) TIA

Answer (score 0):

Because from PHP documentation:

> *l (lowercase 'L')* :    A full textual representation of the day of the week

You can use:

> *U* :    Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)

but in your code you have `$tuesday < $current` that makes no sense, since if `$tuesday`  is less than  `$current` than it is in the past, you should use `>`:

```
<?php
  $current = date('U', strtotime('now'));
  $tuesday = date('U', strtotime('tuesday this week'));
  $thursday = date('U', strtotime('thursday this week'));
  $saturday = date('U', strtotime('saturday this week'));
  if ($tuesday > $current) {
    echo "Tuesday in the future";
  } else if ($thursday > $current) {
    echo "Thursday in the future";
  } else if ($saturday > $current) {
    echo "Saturday in the future";
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you compare variables of `string` type, which will not work as you want.

I used another approach comparing array with list of training which you can modify in the future. I hope this will give you some inspirations.

I used `date('N')` which gives `1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
$trainings = [
    '2' => 'Tuesday',
    '4' => 'Thursday',
    '6' => 'Saturday'
];

$today = date('l');
$todayN = date('N');

if (in_array($today, $trainings)) {
    echo 'Today';
} else {
    $nextTraining = array_values($trainings)[0];
    foreach ($trainings as $n => $day) {
        if ($todayN < $n) {
            $nextTraining = $day;
            break;
        }
    }
    echo $nextTraining;
}
```